# Reading time and date on webpage with Python

Tags: python, html, date, time, web-scraping

New to python, intermediate at VB7

I have been trying to create a program which will reach out and log news articles based on the text in the url. I have encountered many difficulties no doubt due to my unfamiliarity with the language, and I was hoping I might find some help here on this problem as I have others.

Here is an example block of webpage code I am working with. (I'm sorry, I know its ugly.)

```
<tr><td width="130" align="right" style="white-space:nowrap">Aug-29-17 09:05AM&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td align="left">
<a href="https://finance.yahoo.com/news/abeona-therapeutics-receives-fda-breakthrough-130500766.html" target="_blank"
class="tab-link-news">Yahoo news</a><span style="color:#aa6dc0;font-size:9px">GlobeNewswire</span> <span class="body-table-news-gain">
+18.95%</span></td></tr><tr><td width="130" align="right" style="white-space:nowrap">Aug-25-17 07:30AM&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td align="left">
<a href="https://finance.yahoo.com/news/" target="_blank" class="tab-link-news">Corporate News Blog - </a> 
<span style="color:#aa6dc0;font-size:9px">ACCESSWIRE</span> <span class="body-table-news-loss">-5.73%</span></td></tr>
```

I have Beautifulsoup, request, and at this point feel confident enough to handle any other module that I may need.

What I am trying to do figure out now is recording the time and date on the webpage, or perhaps checking it against today's date so that I don't read old news.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Have you tried using a RSS or Atom feed in order to check for new articles? Also, do you know how to make HTTP HEAD requests and check for the modification dates in the headers? For websites that report their dates correctly, this is far safer than scraping HTML code for dates.

Comment: Which time and date? I see two of them in that block.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module.

If you already parsed the string with date and time ("Aug-29-17 09:05AM" in your case) use [datetime.strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to create datetime object.

```
mydate = datetime.datetime.strptime('Aug 29 17 09:05AM', '%b %d %y %I:%M%p')
```

Than you can compare it with today's date - datetime.now().

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to scrap time and date with their responsive content from site's source code then you can do it using [`bs4`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

html = '''
<tr>
   <td width="130" align="right" style="white-space:nowrap">Aug-29-17 09:05AM&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
   <td align="left">
      <a href="https://finance.yahoo.com/news/abeona-therapeutics-receives-fda-breakthrough-130500766.html" target="_blank"
         class="tab-link-news">Yahoo news</a><span style="color:#aa6dc0;font-size:9px">GlobeNewswire</span> <span class="body-table-news-gain">
      +18.95%</span>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td width="130" align="right" style="white-space:nowrap">Aug-25-17 07:30AM&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
   <td align="left">
      <a href="https://finance.yahoo.com/news/" target="_blank" class="tab-link-news">Corporate News Blog - </a> 
      <span style="color:#aa6dc0;font-size:9px">ACCESSWIRE</span> <span class="body-table-news-loss">-5.73%</span>
   </td>
</tr>
'''

import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for i,j in zip(soup.find_all('tr'), soup.find_all('td', attrs={'align':'left'})):
    print '\n[time and date] => {}'.format(i.td.text)
    print '[Content] => {}'.format(re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', str(j)).replace('\n',' '))
    print '[Link] => {}'.format(j.find('a').get('href'))
```

This will give as a result:

```
[time and date] => Aug-29-17 09:05AM
[Content] =>  Yahoo newsGlobeNewswire     +18.95%
[Link] => https://finance.yahoo.com/news/abeona-therapeutics-receives-fda-breakthrough-130500766.html

[time and date] => Aug-25-17 07:30AM
[Content] =>  Corporate News Blog -  ACCESSWIRE -5.73%
[Link] => https://finance.yahoo.com/news/
```

Comment: Ah, okay I think that makes sense. That answered my question, but it seems I hadn't considered the whole problem. I ran the text and ended up with quite a few dates that I'm not certain how to link with specific articles. How would one search a page full of many such </tr> tags for ones that were recent? Could I pinpoint the section I am looking for and screen it for other factors?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the time module:

```
import time
currentTime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
```

it might look frustrating, but its syntax is actually very easy and comprehendable.

I hope I've helped!